# Why am i still being redirected to login.php when my data is correct?

Tags: php

I am being redirected to login.php after login in instead of being redirected to the assigned url. But when I remove the protection code which make sure you have to login before the assigned page would load it works fine but when i insert the protection code, it keeps taking me back to login.php. What might be the problem. Here is the script.

Here is the protection code:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || (trim($_SESSION['login']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

?>

This is the secure page

Here is the login-exec.php script

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$login = clean($_POST['login']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($login == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM bslogin WHERE username='$login' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
$data=array("norendb7" => array("url"=>"insideonbanking-1.php"
                                ,"password"=>"yasinmy20")); 

if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) { 
    if($data[$_POST['login']]['password'] == $_POST['password']) { 
        $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'] . " " . $_POST['password']; 
        header('Location: ' . $data[$_POST['login']]['url']); 
        exit();            
    } else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

?>

Comment: Please choose a proper title.

Comment: It would be a good idea to append at least error codes when you are returning to `login.php`. Something like: `login.php?err=pass`

Comment: please see that you are redirected to login.php from which command. Command in your protection code or from the page given beneath. Please pass different values and confirm it first and accordingly post the result you get.

Comment: Dude, this is the 3rd time you've asked this in 8 hours! http://stackoverflow.com/users/951641/dagrin

Comment: I need it resolve thats why i keep asking...bt got it done. Thanks ya all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) xor (trim($_SESSION['login']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roland....U did help me solve this mess. It is resolved and working fine. Am grateful 2 u.

Comment: @dagrin - Read more about xor here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php